# Set Downloaded Image as BLOB to background in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, web, blob

I have downloaded a BLOB which is an image and want to set it as the background of my page. However all the tutorials I have searched show a BLOB as a URL, but mine is something like this (Logged the downloaded object):
[image: Object Printed when downloaded]

Am I missing something or how can I set this to be the background of my page. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this to a blob URL

```
URL.createObjectURL(Blob)
```

and then add it to the img

```
document.querySelector('img').src = URL.createObjectURL(Blob)
```